# Does subjunctive structure always use 'that' word in the begining? How exactly it works?

Tags: subjunctives

I have an idea about it but not utterly sure how does it work? I read it in books but it's still confusing; for instance, is it mandatory to be preceded always by the word *that*?

Is there any rules on the base form on the sentence?

Comment: Welcome to ELL! Yes, English can be fun! However, I think what you are asking is unclear, especially when you already know how it works. So you know how it works but you don't know how to use it? I think it's the best for you and the site to ask about the usage one case a question, with a clear example of what you intend to use.

Comment: @DamkerngT. Right I'm just new here. I apologize if I didn't put my query to the right section(remember I'm new here). Anyways, thanks for your feedback. Hoping to get a nice answer to my question. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

This is too broad a question to answer. With multiple sources, let me jot down what you want.

There are three moods of English verbs:  *indicative, imperative, and subjunctive.*

The commonest is indicative mood that shows a fact/an opinion or forms a question

> I am going to market. Do you want to come with me?

The imperative mood commands, directs, requests

> Go to the market (to bring bread) -*it takes off the subject of the sentence*

The most complicated is subjunctive mood that shows a wish, suggestion, and attitude. It uses *I were* and such distinctive forms of the verbs.

> If I were you, I would go to market (in spite of heavy rain).

Making the Subjunctive Mood

The present subjunctive takes the most general form of the verb irrespective of the subject

> The priest *advised* that I pray daily.

The past subjunctive uses the same form what the past tense of the verb is.

> I *wish* I *were* God; If I *were* rich, I *could* retire.

When the subjunctive is used, use the *past subjunctive in contrary-to-fact* clauses stating conditional statement. These statements generally takes *if*.

For *present contrary-to-fact* clauses, the past tense of the verb is used. And, use *were* in case of the verb is *to be*.

> If I *were* in New York, I *would* witness every celebration happening on the Times Square. 
>   I *wish* I *were* tall dark and handsome, but I *am* short, fair and ugly.

For *past contrary-to-fact clauses*, the past perfect of the verb (had + past participle) is used.

> If Rocky *had studied* harder, he *would not have been* failed.

Use the *present subjunctive* in sentences expressing suggestions, needs, or requests.  Such instances take verbs like *ask, recommend, etc.* **These verbs often take *that* (your concern in question).**

> The teacher *insisted* **that** Rocky *study* hard to get good numbers. 
>   The priest *asks* **that** each disciple *pray* four times in a day.

[Good read here.](http://www.grammar-monster.com/glossary/subjunctive_mood.htm)

Comment: Thanks for your answers! I really appreciate it. Just to be cleared. I need to now when you're constructing sentence in subjunctive, does it have to have the word "that"? Many thanks

Comment: @Rolan no not necessary **(I wish it were still in use).** In some cases it happens. Read the answer full.

Comment: @Rolan also, it's just to be *clear* ;)