# Present tense in the past

Tags: sentence-construction, past-tense, present-tense

I am reading the book 'The Man Who Mistook His Wife For a Hat' by Oliver Sacks. On page 104 there is this sentence:

> Feeling that Ray also had such possibilities in him, that, despite his own words, he was not incorrigibly centred on his own disease, in an exhibitionistic or narcissistic way, I suggested that we **meet** weekly for a period of three months.

Neither before or after this sentence is the present tense used, that is, he is narrating a story in the past. Is this a mistake, or actually we can use the present tense in the past to describe a routine (even if that routine no longer exists in the present)?

Comment: It's not the present tense, it's the infinitive.  They just happen to look the same here.

Comment: Not an infinitive. Infinitives do not have subjects

Answer (score 1):

The problem you adressed is in connection with the use of the verb **suggest**.

There are many possible alternatives:

> He suggested that Mary **should leave** earlier.
>
> He suggested **leaving** earlier. (the subject is also part of leaving)
>
> He suggested that Mary **left**. (**NOT** He suggested Mary to leave earlier.)

However, there's still another option for the use of *suggest*:

> I suggest that you **do** this exercise at home. (Present Subjunctive is used in case of direct demand or suggestion)

Comment: Thank you:) But your in your last example did you want to write  _I **suggest** that you do this exercise at home._ or _I **suggested** that you do this exercise at home._ ?

Comment: To be more precise, this is the present Subjunctive

Answer (score 0):

> I suggested that we **meet** weekly for a period of three months.

**meet** in this sentence is not the present tense but the infinitive.

Thanks @stangdon for your comment.

Comment: That's not an inifinite as it is governed by a subject "we"

Comment: In my country it is the Past imperfect of subjunctive, so I supposed that in English it would be past tense. That's why the question. Why is this verb in the present tense?

Comment: English has two forms of the subjunctive, but we use the present subjunctive with commands since the occur in the future relative to the time of speaking.

Comment: Thank you:) btw, if you do it in form of answer I will accept it:)

Comment: Just to clarify (because I am not sure if it will influence a potential answer), this sentence refers to something that does not include the present(time of the narration)- The period of three months is already gone. The narration is totally centred in the past. Thank you in advance.

Comment: This answer kind of is related: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/20356/22904 The example: _The priest advised that I **pray** daily_. refers to my question, although **pray** in that context may mean something to do 'forever', not something that made sense in the past, but does not make sense in the present. I hope you understand what I mean.